# Unable to manipulate element created by appendChild()

Tags: javascript, es6-modules, html-templates

I'm pulling my hair out on this one. I have a JavaScript class that clones a `<template>` element and then is appended to the document body. I want to then manipulate that newly created element... but it always insists it's undefined.

**Template**

```
<template id="js-modalTemplate">
    <aside class="o--modal" style="display: none">
        <button class="o-modal__close-button">
            Close
        </button>
        <div><iframe class="js-video" src=""></iframe></div>
    </aside>
</template>
```

**ES Module**

```
export default class Modal {
  constructor() {
    const template = document.getElementById('js-modalTemplate');
    const modalTemplate = template.content.cloneNode(true)

    this.modalElement = document.body.appendChild(modalTemplate)

    console.log(this.modalElement)

    this.modalElement.style.display = "block"
  }
}
```

**Script element**

```
<script type="module">
   import VideoModal from "{{ Vite::asset('resources/js/components/Modal.js') }}"

   window.testModal = new Modal()
</script>
```

The console.log output of the element **sometimes** appears in full, but **sometimes** it's empty (no changes to code)...

Empty fragment:

[image]

Fragment with content:

[image]

However I always get the following error, no matter what:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'display')

And the element always appears in the DOM at the expected place.

**Things I've tried**

- Moving the script element to the bottom of `document.body` and adding `defer`. (Neither of these things should be necessary because it's an ES Module anyway and so it automatically deferred.)
- Placing the code within `window.onload` for similar reasons

There's just something about using a `<template>` that causes this issue, but I've never used them before so I don't know what!

Comment: Given you have a [DocumentFragment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DocumentFragment), what makes you think the `style` property will be defined?

Comment: There really doesn't seem to be any reason for the `<aside>` to be initially hidden with `display: none`. What is your reasoning for doing so?

Comment: @Phil Excellent question. I mistakenly assumed it meant something more than it does... However, I'm still not sure why `appendChild()` isn't returning the element that's been created

Comment: @Phil `display: none` is irrelevant. This is just test code to see if I can manipulate the new element

Comment: Did you read [the docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild)? _"**Return value:** A Node that is the appended child (aChild), except when aChild is a DocumentFragment, in which case the empty DocumentFragment is returned."_

Comment: I'd try working with `modalTemplate` instead of the return value from `appendChild()`

Comment: @Phil That's where I started. I had the same issue working with the `modalTemplate` so I tried to work with the return value of `appendChild()` instead. Ultimately I need to be able to manipulate the newly created element either way.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253869/discussion-between-chuck-le-butt-and-phil).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could get the top level element (the `<aside>`) from the fragment through [`firstElementChild`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/firstElementChild) before appending it to the DOM.

```js
this.modalElement = modalTemplate.firstElementChild;
document.body.appendChild(modalTemplate);
```

Comment: Working example: https://jsfiddle.net/ej4xd0vo/

Comment: Ah, that's all it was. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is that the template content represents a [DocumentFragment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DocumentFragment)...

> It is used as a lightweight version of Document that stores a segment of a document structure comprised of nodes

That is, it is a container for the content, not the content itself.

If you want to operate on any particular node like the `<aside>`, you need to locate it within the fragment.

For example, using the [firstElementChild](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/firstElementChild) property

```js
const template = document.getElementById("js-modalTemplate");

const content = template.content.cloneNode(true).firstElementChild;
console.log('style.display:', content.style.display);
```

```html
<template id="js-modalTemplate">
  <aside class="o--modal" style="display: none">
    <button class="o-modal__close-button">
      Close
    </button>
    <div><iframe class="js-video" src=""></iframe></div>
  </aside>
</template>
```